# How to get a specific row for testing and other for training?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-mining

I want to test a specific row from my dataset and to see the result, but I don't know how to do it. For example I want to test row number 100 and then to see the accuracy.

```
feature_cols = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
X = df[feature_cols] # Features
y = df[6] # Target variable

# Split dataset into training set and test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=1,
                                                    random_state=1)

#Create Decision Tree classifer object
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=5)

#Train Decision Tree Classifer
clf = clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

#Predict the response for test dataset
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

print("Accuracy:", metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

Comment: Do you know the index of the row you want to test?

Comment: For example to test the last row in dataset and all other rows for training

Comment: In that case don't use train_test_split to split your data.

Comment: And how to do? Do you have any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend excluding the row you want to test from the dataset.

```
test_row=100
train_idx=np.arange(X.shape[0])!=test_row
test_idx=np.arange(X.shape[0])==test_row
X_train=X[train_idx]
y_train=y[train_idx]
X_test=X[test_idx]
y_test=y[test_idx]
```

Now X_test will contain a single row. However, the accuracy will now be either 0 or 1 since you are only testing one sample.